# Azure Runbook - automation account - "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Resource group 'XXXX' could not be found

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am receiving the following error:
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Resource group 'GFPS-P-EUW-RG-25497128-EcommerceServices-D' could not be found.

I have checked that the resource group of both my automation account and the database I want to access are in the same resource group, with no result.

What could be wrong? What error could I have?

```
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $DatabaseServerName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseAdminUsername,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseAdminPassword,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$DatabaseNames,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageAccountName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$BlobStorageEndpoint,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$StorageKey,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$BlobContainerName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]$RetentionDays
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'

# Import this library to get the new features of the script
Import-Module Az.Sql

function Login() {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure..." -Verbose

        Connect-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

        #Add-AzureRmAccount `
        #   -ServicePrincipal `
        #   -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        #   -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        #   -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
}

function Create-Blob-Container([string]$blobContainerName, $storageContext) {
    Write-Verbose "Checking if blob container '$blobContainerName' already exists" -Verbose
    if (Get-AzureStorageContainer -ErrorAction "Stop" -Context $storageContext | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $blobContainerName }) {
        Write-Verbose "Container '$blobContainerName' already exists" -Verbose
    } else {
        New-AzureStorageContainer -ErrorAction "Stop" -Name $blobContainerName -Permission Off -Context $storageContext
        Write-Verbose "Container '$blobContainerName' created" -Verbose
    }
}

function Export-To-Blob-Storage([string]$resourceGroupName, [string]$databaseServerName, [string]$databaseAdminUsername, [string]$databaseAdminPassword, [string[]]$databaseNames, [string]$storageKey, [string]$blobStorageEndpoint, [string]$blobContainerName) {
    Write-Verbose "Starting database export to databases '$databaseNames'" -Verbose
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $databaseAdminPassword –AsPlainText -Force 
    $creds = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $databaseAdminUsername, $securePassword

    foreach ($databaseName in $databaseNames.Split(",").Trim()) {
        Write-Output "Creating request to backup database '$databaseName'"

        $bacpacFilename = $databaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"
        $bacpacUri = $blobStorageEndpoint + $blobContainerName + "/" + $bacpacFilename

        $exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName –ServerName $databaseServerName `
            –DatabaseName $databaseName –StorageKeytype "StorageAccessKey" –storageKey $storageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
            –AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName –AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password -ErrorAction "Stop"
        
        # Print status of the export
        Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink -ErrorAction "Stop"
    }
}

function Delete-Old-Backups([int]$retentionDays, [string]$blobContainerName, $storageContext) {
    Write-Output "Removing backups older than '$retentionDays' days from blob: '$blobContainerName'"
    $isOldDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-$retentionDays)
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blobContainerName -Context $storageContext
    foreach ($blob in ($blobs | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $isOldDate -and $_.BlobType -eq "BlockBlob" })) {
        Write-Verbose ("Removing blob: " + $blob.Name) -Verbose
        Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.Name -Container $blobContainerName -Context $storageContext
    }
}

Write-Verbose "Starting database backup" -Verbose

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

Login

Create-Blob-Container `
    -blobContainerName $blobContainerName `
    -storageContext $storageContext
    
Export-To-Blob-Storage `
    -resourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -databaseServerName $DatabaseServerName `
    -databaseAdminUsername $DatabaseAdminUsername `
    -databaseAdminPassword $DatabaseAdminPassword `
    -databaseNames $DatabaseNames `
    -storageKey $StorageKey `
    -blobStorageEndpoint $BlobStorageEndpoint `
    -blobContainerName $BlobContainerName
    
Delete-Old-Backups `
    -retentionDays $RetentionDays `
    -storageContext $StorageContext `
    -blobContainerName $BlobContainerName
    
Write-Verbose "Database backup script finished" -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try running the cmdlet New-AzSqlDatabaseExport directly from Azure Cloud Shell or from any local setup to understand if its Azure Automation level issue or not. Also as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseexport?view=azps-9.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-8.2.0), value for the resource group parameter should be the one related to resource group of the SQL Database Server. Hope you have provided the resource group of the SQL Database Server.